# Crear lista de 3 columnas con datos de un Array

Tags: array, angular, lista, typescript, angular7

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto de Angular 7 en el cual tengo que crear una lista de usuarios de tres columnas con sus diferentes atributos, el diseño visual seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro crearla, me sale como si fuera una lista vertical de una columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que llevo, aclaro soy nuevo en Angular:

**politicians.service.ts**

```
 getPolitician(): Observable<any[]> {
    // ['added', 'modified', 'removed']
    return this.politicianCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((actions) => {
        return actions.map((a) => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          return { id: a.payload.doc.id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

**list-diputados.component.ts**

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.politicians = this.politiciansService.getPolitician();
    this.cargarDatosTabla();
}

  cargarDatosTabla() {
    this.politicians.forEach((poldata) => {

        this.data = poldata;
        this.diputados = this.data.filter(function(dip_fil){
            return dip_fil.tipoPolitico == 'Diputado';
        });

    });

}
```

**list-diputados.component.html**

```
   <nb-layout-column style="background-color: #ffffff">
<table>
  <nb-list>
    <nb-list-item *ngFor="let item of diputados">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <nb-user size="large" [name]="item.name +' '+item.lastName" [title]="item.partidoPolitico"></nb-user>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </nb-list-item>
  </nb-list>
</table>
```

Estoy usando Nebular es un KIT UI por eso las etiquetas NB.

Comment: Qué es lo que te falla?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera acabo de agregar la imagen de como se visualiza en mi proyecto actual como una lista de una columna, la idea es visualizarlo como la imagen 1 como una lista de 3 columnas.

Comment: Me percate que estas utilizando nebular para construir tu `HTML`; lamentablemente nunca he trabajado con esa librería o paquete, por lo que no podría decirte si eso puede ser una causa, sin embargo me percato que no estas utilizando **bootstrap** el cual puede solucionar rápidamente tu problema

Comment: Gracias Paulo, efectivamente solo fue una cuestion de utilizar los grids bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes incluir **Bootstrap** tal como lo explica en [este enlace](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/bootstrap-integration#related-articles). Ya con esto, utiliza el sistema de grid para ajustar los tres elementos por fila:

```
<nb-list>
  <nb-list-item *ngFor="let item of diputados">
    <nb-user class="col-4" size="large" [name]="item.name +' '+item.lastName" [title]="item.partidoPolitico"></nb-user>
  </nb-list-item>
</nb-list>
```

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado, son esos momentos que te bloqueas con algo tan basico. Lo  use de la siguiente manera: `<div class="col-4" *ngFor="let item of diputados">` porque dentro de la etiqueta del usuario reduce el contenido de la etiqueta `<nb-user>`.